# Initializing an array of zeroes

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer

It is well known that missing initializers for an array of scalars are defaulted to zero.

```
int A[5]; // Entries remain uninitialized
int B[5]= { 0 }; // All entries set to zero
```

But is this (below) guaranteed ?

```
int C[5]= { }; // All entries set to zero
```

Comment: [Read about aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I already read about array initializers. This particular explanation is more obscure than anything else.

Comment: @M.M: tag as duplicate, then.

Comment: well, similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840514/

Comment: @mm: mh, my question is specifically about empty braces, which seem to never appear in examples. One (me) may be tempted to believe that they amount to no braces at all. That's what I needed to check.

Comment: OK. The `B` and `C` in your question are actually covered by the same rule , any entries not given initializers are zero-initialized

Comment: This is why [`{0}` is confusing/misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797810/560648).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The empty braced initialisation performs aggregation-initialization of the array: this leads to zero-initialization of the `int` elements.

Yes, this is guaranteed.

Comment: `int C[5]` is not a class type, so value-initialization is not performed, aggregate initialization is performed.

Comment: @Holt: and ? Does this change the conclusion ?

Comment: @Holt whether it's a class type or not does not impact whether aggregate initialization is performed. All array initialization is aggregate initialization. Also, aggregate initialization is defined such that members with no initializer are value-initialized (which is equivalent to zero-initialization, for `int`)

Comment: @M.M Well, the standard says *"[...] and T is a class type with a default constructor [...] Otherwise, if T is an aggregate type [...]"*, so whether it's a class type or not matters (I am not talking about `int` here, I am talking about `int[5]`). Since here `T` is `int[5]`, `T` is an array type, not a class type, so aggregate initialization is performed, not value-initialization. The elements of `C` will then be value-initialized, but the first thing that is "done" is aggregate-initialization. I was not pointing out the conclusion, simply the wording of the answer.

Comment: @Holt: decrypting the C++ standard is an endless game.

Comment: @Holt if `T` is an array type, it is not a class type

Comment: @M.M Yes, that's exactly what I said in my comment.

Comment: @Holt this question is only about array initialization so I'm not sure where you're coming from

Comment: @M.M `int C[5] = {}` is [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) with `T = int[5]`, by the standard this will performs aggregate initialization, but the **initial answer** was mentioning value-initialization, which would be the case if `T` was a class type with default constructor. I just pointed out that what was happening here was aggregate initialization, not value-initialization.

Comment: @M.M You and I are telling the same thing since the first comment, you probably did not see the original answer which is why you are confusing the meaning of my comments (just look at the edit revision).

Comment: Indeed I did edit it to use better terminology, following the useful comments from @Holt.

Comment: I am always wondering how people know that kind of stuff. I mean how do you know that this " aggregation-initialization"? What are your sources, if I may ask?

Comment: @trilolil Stroustrup is pretty comprehensive, and answering questions on this site helps you retain and hone such knowledge.

Answer (score 38):

Yes, according to the rule of [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), it's guaranteed (that all elements of array `C` will be [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), i.e. [zero-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) to `0` in this case).

(emphasis mine)

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or **initializer list is completely empty**, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).

---

PS:

```
int A[5]; // Entries remain uninitialized
```

"remain uninitialized" might not be accurate. For `int A[5];`, all elements of `A` will be [default-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). If `A` is static or thread-local object, the elements will be [zero-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) to `0`, otherwise nothing is done, they'll be indeterminate values.

Comment: Since you're quoting some formal specification (you should say which one, actually), `A[5]`, properly, is _default-initialized_.

Answer (score 14):

In fact when you say`int A[5] = { 0 };`
you are saying: Initialize the first element to zero. All the other positions are initialized to zero because of the aggregate inizialization.

This line is the real responsible for having your array full of zeroes: `int A[5] = {  };`

That is why if you use `int A[5] = { 1 };` you will only have the first position inizialized to 1.

Comment: But OP's asking about empty initializer list.

Comment: @songyuanyao already answered by other users. Just making the point more clear

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as arrays have a different behavior for initializer lists.

Answer (score 0):

At first, let's prove why every element in the below array A should be zero

```
int A[5] = {0};
```

How to guaranteed? It involves the below standards:

1. It is a [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) since it is array type, and its number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members, and the first element is copy-initialized as 0.

> Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element, or non-static class member, **in order of array subscript/appearance** in the class definition, is **copy-initialized** from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

2. The remaining elements in the array will follow the rule of Aggregate initialization rule, and do value-initialization

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) copy-initialized from empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs **value-initialization for non-class types** and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

3. According to [Value Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), the left 4 elements will routine into 'zero initialization' process

> otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

4. According to [Zero Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), the type of remaining elements is int which is a scaler type, so the left 4 elements will be initialized as 0

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.

5. So every element in A should be zero

Proof done!

Finally, let's prove why every element in the below array B should be zero

```
int B[5] = {};
```

It is a value-initialization form, according to [Value Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.

It will go into upper aggregate-initialization #2, and then every element in B array should be zero.

Proof done!

Comment: The correct answer was accepted five years ago.

Comment: The original answer can't be proven with the strict proof, so it can't say it is guaranteed for all C/C++ compiler

Comment: "can't be proven with the strict proof": what does that mean ?

Comment: Ok, delete the answer? I didn't find any cite from C/C++ specification to prove the related statement, and then it can't be guaranteed, right? Maybe you are a C/C++ professor, but for the some guys, I think it may need more information and cite from C/C++ specification to show what happened from the compiler level.

Comment: Don't make such a fuss of it. The question was essentially about "is it UB or not ?"